# Set up Oracle Virtualbox LAN-ONLY Network

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I need to set up Oracle VM Virtualbox in such a way that some of my virtual machines connect strictly to the LAN. Not to be confused with the WAN; these virtual machines should have ***no outside internet connection!*** Only a connection to other computers on the LAN.

So the virtual machine should:

- Be able to connect to and share data with other computers on the network.
- Be **unable** to connect directly to the internet for *any* reason.
- (optional but preferred) Be able to connect to various aspects of my LAN including my router (192.168.x.x) and my modem.

I have tried VLAN, a secondary ethernet set to Link-Local only, and various connection settings in Oracle Virtualbox.

I am using XUbuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of to solve this is to set the DNS addresses of those VMs nics to 127.0.0.1

If they are WIN OS then go to network adapter settings and if they are Ubuntu based OS then go to `/etc/network/interfaces` to change the dns address

#### update

OK I have just tried this out and it works!

You can access the LAN only and there is no internet for those machines. In windows just set the NIC settings like this. (sorry it's on german but I think you will know where to find these settings)

[image]

I will update it for linux OS (ubuntu based) as soon as i get to my pc